# Snap install of IDEA updated automatically to EAP

Tags: snap, intellij

I have used snap to install Jetbrains IDEA a while ago, which worked flawlessly.

Snap has updated IDEA to their EAP branch(Early access Program).

Since i am just interested in a working and stable IDE i do not prefer this over the most up to date stable version(which snap updated to before this occurence)

Is there a way to reconfigure this inside snap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the installation of your snap application from the `--edge` or newest version to the `--stable` version by running the following:

```
sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-community --stable --classic
```

If you want to go back to the bleeding edge version, run it as:

```
sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-community --edge --classic
```

Or you can also run it in beta as well:

```
sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-community --beta --classic
```

If you want to see all the versions that are available to be installed or switch to use `snap info`

Example:

```
~$ snap info intellij-idea-community 
name:      intellij-idea-community
summary:   Capable & Ergonomic Java IDE
publisher: jetbrains✓
contact:   https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/
license:   unset
description: |
  IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is a free and open-source edition of
  IntelliJ IDEA, the commercial Java IDE by JetBrains. IntelliJ IDEA
  Community Edition provides all the tools you need for Java, Groovy, Kotlin,
  Scala, and Android. It offers instant and clever code completion,
  on-the-fly code analysis, and reliable refactoring tools. Mission-critical
  tools such as integrated version controls systems and a wide variety of
  supported languages and frameworks are at hand — no plugin hustle included.
commands:
  - intellij-idea-community
snap-id:      KSPcSedMkvhgEjkg3Ki1PdjX2Ylm2aOy
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 08:17 MDT
channels:                                   
  stable:           2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  candidate:        2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  beta:             2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  edge:             2018.3-EAP   (87) 500MB classic
  2018.3/stable:    –                       
  2018.3/candidate: –                       
  2018.3/beta:      –                       
  2018.3/edge:      2018.3-EAP   (87) 500MB classic
  2018.2/stable:    2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  2018.2/candidate: 2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  2018.2/beta:      2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
  2018.2/edge:      2018.2.5-EAP (86) 481MB classic
  2018.1/stable:    2018.1.6     (65) 495MB classic
  2018.1/candidate: ↑                       
  2018.1/beta:      ↑                       
  2018.1/edge:      ↑                       
  2017.3/stable:    2017.3.5     (36) 425MB classic
  2017.3/candidate: ↑                       
  2017.3/beta:      ↑                       
  2017.3/edge:      ↑                       
installed:          2018.2.4     (83) 481MB classic
```

Hope this helps!